# If $\frac{X_a}{X_a+Y_a}$ and $\frac{X_b}{X_b+Y_b}$ are correlated, what about $X_a+Y_a$ and $X_b+Y_b$

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

Suppose I have four normal random variables:$X_a$,$Y_a$,$X_b$,$Y_b$.

$X_a$ and $Y_a$ follow bivariate normal, $X_b$ and $Y_b$ also follow bivariate normal.

let $Z_a=\frac{X_a}{X_a+Y_a}$ , $Z_b=\frac{X_b}{X_b+Y_b}$ and 
$Z_a\,Z_b=p$,
p is a known constant.

Can I calculate the correlation between $X_a+Y_a$ and $X_b+Y_b$

Comment: $*$ denotes convolution, $\cdot$ denotes multiplication

Comment: @AdamLuo: do you have a practical and reproducible instance when $Z_a\,Z_b=p$ can occur? does occur?

Answer (score 3):

Since$$X_a+Y_a=\frac{p}{Y_b+X_b}$$it seems impossible that both $Y_b+X_b$ and 
$X_a+Y_a$ are Normal variates. The question is thus void *imho*.

Note also that since $$\frac{X_b}{Y_b+X_b}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{Y_b}{X_b}}$$ and since $Y_b/X_b$ is a Cauchy variate, it is quite likely that the correlation between $$\frac{X_b}{Y_b+X_b}\text{ and }\frac{X_a}{Y_a+X_a}$$ does not exist.